# How to avoid Zuul becoming a bottleneck

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, netflix-eureka

I'm working on a microservice architecture with Ribbon/Eureka/Hystrix and Zuul, everything is working fine. But as we're working with microservices, we can scale our microservices as we want and have different instances of the same µservice. For now, load balancing is working great with one instance of Zuul, different Eureka instances made as cluster and different instances of µservices. The question is: can I define more than one instance of Zuul? If yes, doesn't Zuul can be accessed using different ports and is losing the reverse-proxy role that's making its strength? 'cause for now, I see it as a single point of failure and a potential bottleneck.

**Can someone please explain how to avoid this problem?**

Answer (score 1):

> can I define more than one instance of Zuul?

You can and actually you should define more than one instance for a complex microservice system build with spring-cloud in my opinion.

> doesn't Zuul can be accessed using different ports and is losing the
>   reverse-proxy role that's making its strength?

multiple instances in distribution system may increase fault tolerance ability and can deal with more complex routing in your microserver-sys what if you design for, and it's not has much association for its strength.(may be i just misunderstand OP's meaning?)

I think zuul's role is like a software-api-gateway for microservice, not only proxy but *Authentication*, *Dynamic Routing*, *Security*... and in spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul, it has `Ribbon` and `Hystrix` dependencies for load balance and circuit breakers. Zuul is part of spring-cloud's mircoservice solution and dealing gateway work just like normal network gateway.

Thought that it is difficult answer to say Zuul is(or isn't) a bottleneck.
May the question's point is `How to avoid network-gateway becoming a bottleneck`?

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is valid. You can also avoid `Zuul` from becoming a bottle-neck by registering multiple instances and putting them behind a `cloud-based load-balancer` such as `AWS ALB`, which will scale to meet traffic demands.